# Ionic Material datetime picker

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I need a datetime picker for my Ionic Material app. I have tested a lot of plugins but none of them seem to work very well because graphic's flickening or code don't working very well.
I have tested these two plugins: 
Onezone datepicker http://market.ionic.io/plugins/onezone-datepicker , that have a nice graphic but don't have a time picker;
ion-datetime-picker https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker , that is perfect as code but for graphic it isn't the top.

Can you give me some nice plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/thomasdtucker/IonicMaterial and then use the standard DateTime picker from @angular/material.